# How to remove an element from an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Can't seem to find a way on how to do it....

for example if I have an array

```
a = { 1,2,3 }
```

and I want to delete a[1] so the result would be

```
a = { 1,3 }
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: Note that if you will be doing this a lot an array probably isn't the right data structure for your problem. A linked list or some kind of tree might work better

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is move all of the elements after the removed element up by 1 and keep a size counter that tells you the number of elements currently in the array. A C array is not much more than a block of contiguous memory, and it can't be resized in place.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the array has been declared as `static` or has automatic storage duration then you can't do it since you have no way to alter the effective size of the array.

One workaround could be to shift all the elements past the one that is going to be removed to the left and then update a secondary variable used to store the effective length of the array.

If the array has been dynamically allocated then you can just allocate a new, shorter, array. Copy all the elements minus the one that is going to be deleted and you are done.

Comment: How do you create a static array? Is any array you don't define as a constant?

Comment: You just put the static prefix when you're declaring the array: ```static int a = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @BackSlash `static` and `const`are different things: In C there are three storage durations: static, auto and allocated. ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.2.4 – 1. Jack simply wants to say "not of allocated storage duration" and did this formally correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could just shift the desired elements depending on the index to delete like so:

Edit: more robust to just copy over to a new array, then would no longer need to ignore last element when just working with one array.

```
int a = {1, 2, 3};
int new_a[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) - 1]; // new array will hold one less value
int pos = 3; // delete the item at the third index

for (i = pos - 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) - 1; i++) {
    new_a[i] = a[i+1];
}
```

Comment: I see, will try to implement this. Thank you.

Comment: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`  would be better than `sizeof(a)/4`, rather than assuming `int` is 4 bytes.  Also, with this approach it's necessary to keep track of how much of the array is being used, or you'll have unwanted leftovers at the end after you delete some elements.   With your example code above, the array contents don't change -- it's still `{1, 2, 3}` at the end, unless you know to ignore the last element after the delete.  If you'd deleted the 2nd instead of the third, you'd have `{1, 3, 3}` -- where the array contents change, but you still need to ignore the last element after.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove an element from an array in C?
>   How can this be done ?

Elements of an array in C cannot be deleted.

An element can be ignored, but not deleted.  The `sizeof(a)` cannot change.  Once the array is defined, the number of elements is fixed.

Perhaps a new approach to your higher level task?

Comment: What would suggest? I'm trying to write my implementation of selection sort. So after finding the minimum value of a given array I need to remove or ignore it. So the next time the loop goes around. It will find the next min value and so on.

Comment: Use a different data structure instead of a C array. Someone suggested a linked list, the answer I gave above is very expensive every time you want to delete an element -- O(n) performance, but a linked list I believe is O(1).

Comment: @BackSlash Suggest to search the question with "how to remove data involving a section sort." Upon not finding one, post your question showing what you have done and where the challenge exist.

Comment: Using a linked list is O(1), but that 1 is probably much larger than the array's N in most cases because of data locality. I think the linked list would be a fine choice, just thought I'd mention it since the performance benefits won't show up in most cases on a real machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with array. Use linked list instead.

Comment: About to start my research on linked lists. Thank you for your help.